# Does Lollipop changed behavior of SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

Following query returns expected result on Android < 5.0

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACT_FTS WHERE CONTACT_DETAILS MATCH '*test*'
```

But on Lollipop it does not return anything

I have used FTS4 to create tables.

Is there any workaround to get in between result same as `*test*` , which will return me containing `test` in results

Comment: is this command working below 5.0

Comment: Yes, it works as expected below 5.0.

Comment: are you testing in which user account (multiple user account) ?

Answer (score 0):

This query does not work *correctly* even before 5.0.

SQLite's FTS module supports only prefix searches, i.e., `something*`.

Comment: Is there any way in FTS we can achieve same result?